# How to create user define function in sqlite and use it in phonegap android

Tags: android, cordova, android-sqlite, user-defined-functions

I am creating an android app using phone-gap. What i want to know is how to create a user define function in sq-lite and use same in the phone-gap.
I search in sq-lite for the same but didn't find exact solutions. 
Giving an details example will be great help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is not practical in Cordova/PhoneGap for reasons described in https://github.com/litehelpers/Cordova-sqlite-storage/issues/741.